# How to get the return value of a function by using 'this' in javascript in below context

Tags: javascript, json, function, this, var

Hi i'm trying to call a function which is an attribute value in a JSON.

Getting different results in different scenarios

```
var x = 3;
var foo = {
    x: 2,
    inner: {
        x: 1,
        reValue: function() {
            return this.x
        }
    }
}

var go = foo.inner.reValue;
```

Case 1:

```
console.log(go()) // 3
```

Case 2:

```
console.log(foo.inner.reValue()) // 1
```

Can anyone explain case 1?

Comment: Please properly format your question next time...

Comment: In the first case, `this` refers to the window object, which has a variable `x=3`, while in the second case `this` is the `foo` object, where `x=2`

Answer (score 3):

Creating a variable in global scope, automatically assigns it to `window`, so:

```
 var x = 3;
 var go = foo.inner.reValue;
 go()
```

does the same as:

```
 window.x = 3;
 window.go = foo.inner.reValue;
 window.go();
```

And the last line will call `go` with the context (aka `this`) being `window`, therefore `this.x` will be `window.x`.

> If a function is called on an object, such as in `obj.myMethod()` or the equivalent `obj["myMethod"]()`, then ThisBinding is set to the object (`obj` in the example; §13.2.1).  ~ [How does the this keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the context.

If you re-bind `go` to `foo.inner`, it behaves as intended:

```
go=go.bind(foo.inner)
```

Or initially:

```
var go = foo.inner.reValue.bind(foo.inner);
```

As long as you did not specify the context, the global context (in case of a browser this is `window`) is chosen per default.

So `this` refers in your example to `window.x`, which is `3`

Answer (score 0):

The value of this is determined based upon **where** the function was called. Here is an example:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: this,
  baz: function() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

console.log(foo.bar); // logs window
foo.baz();            // logs foo

let hey = foo.baz;

hey();                // logs window
```

A new value of `this` is created **when a method is invoked on a object**. Therefore, our first log logs window because we haven't invoked any method. However, our second example logs foo because now a method on foo is called and therefore the value of `this` inside the baz function is foo. You can usually derive the value of this taking the object left of the dot of the function which is called.

For example `foo.baz()`, foo is left of the dot of `baz()` so foo is the value of `this`.

The last example is a bit tricky. The function object gets stored inside the variable hey. Now when hey gets executed it will log `window`. This is because the value of this is determined when `hey()` gets executed. Because hey is a global variable it sits on the window object. Using the rule we just learned we can take the object left of the dot of `hey()`. This is window, because all variables on the global scope are `window.variable`.

If you fully want to understand the value of this you should also know how the execution context works in JS. [Here](https://codeburst.io/js-demystified-04-execution-context-97dea52c8ac6) is some information about that.

Answer (score -1):

this.x may be "local" to the function by interpretation.
remove the "this" to de-localize , but if that has trouble you may need to write in a way that disambiguates x.

Comment: This is not java?!

Comment: @JonasW. I think, Samuel didn't intentionally write something `java-ish` but did not make him clear either.

Comment: @thomas i dont think so. `remove the "this"` will not work.

Comment: @JonasW. that was not, what I said ;)